# What is for () function correct use here

Tags: c

I'm trying to make a code that checks if a password contains a number, an uppercase letter, and a `$` symbol with `for` function, but if I add the {} to the `for` function it won't work.

If I do it like this it won't work:

```
  for (x = 0; x <= 10; x++) {
    if (isdigit(password[x])) {
      number++;
    }
  } // why does removing the {} from for make it work
```

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <string.h>

int main() {
  int x = 10, uppercase = 0, number = 0, dollar = 0;
  char password[x];

  printf("enter password: ");
  scanf(" %s", &password);

  /* If I do it like this it wont work.  Why?
  for (x = 0; x <= 10; x++) {
    if (isdigit(password[x])) {
      number++;
    }
  }
  */

  for (x = 0; x <= 10; x++)
    if (isdigit(password[x])) {
      number++;
    }

  for (x = 0; x <= 10; x++)
    if (isupper(password[x])) {
      uppercase++;
    }

  for (x = 0; x <= 10; x++)
    if (password[x] == '$') {
      dollar++;
    }

  if ((number >= 1) && (uppercase >= 1) && (dollar >= 1)) {
    printf("password saved");
  } else {
    printf("invalid password");
  }

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: `for` is not a function, it's a *statement*. And the curly braces should not matter. And please include the *non* working code in your question instead (so we get a [mcve] that is easier for us to try ourselves). Also please take some time to read about [how to ask good questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) as well as [this question checklist](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist/), and please learn how to use a debugger to step through your code statement by statement.

Comment: `for(x=0;x<=10;x++)` - when `i==10`, you access `password` out of bounds.

Comment: Your problem is not the `{}`.  Your problem is that you're always trying to inspect exactly 10 characters -- but that's not necessarily the actual number of characters in the password you entered.  Use `strlen()` to find the length of the password that was actually entered.  (And since strings in C are always terminated by a null character, your array of size 10 can actually only store passwords of length at most 9.)

Answer (score 0):

Various problems

**Limit input**

Use a width limit modifier and do not pass the address of the array.  Pass the array (no `&`) and that will convert to the address of the first element of the array.  Leading `" "` not needed in the format as `"%s"` tosses optional leading white-space already.

```
int x = 10;
char password[x];
// scanf(" %s", &password);
scanf("%9s", password);
```

Little reason to be stingy in buffer size.  Suggest:

```
char password[80];
scanf("%79s", password);
```

**Iterate to the null character**

```
// Bad! this iterates 11 times!
// for (x = 0; x <= 10; x++)

// Iterate up to the null character
for (x = 0; password[x]; x++)
```

**Advanced: `is...()`**

`is...(int ch)` is valid for values in the `unsigned char` range and `EOF`.  Insure other negative values are not passed.

```
// if (isupper(password[x]))
if (isupper((unsigned char) password[x]))
```

---

Might as well use one loop.

```
for (x = 0; password[x]; x++) {
  if (isdigit((unsigned char) password[x])) {
    number++;
  } else if (isupper((unsigned char) password[x])) {
    uppercase++;
  } else if (password[x] == '$') {
    dollar++;
  }
}
```

---

**Advanced: security**

Good to scrub memory when done with passwords.

```
volatile char *p = password; 
for (x = 0; x < sizeof password; x++)
  p[x] = 0;
}
```

Note: `memset(password ...)` is no good as it may be optimize out.